# nloptr COBYLA method does not recognize equality constraints in R

Tags: r, optimization, mathematical-optimization, nlopt

I'm now running nloptr-COBYLA minimization model in R
I followed nloptr interface and got the solution from the objective minimization convergence. But the solution does not satisfy constraints.
Is there anyone who can find my mistake in code?...

**CODE**

```
       eval_f<-function(x){                                                        
    -(CCC-a1*x[1]^(0.9)-a2*x[2]^(0.9)-a3*x[3]^(0.9)-b1*x[4]^(0.9)
-b2*x[5]^(0.9)-b3*x[6]^(0.9)-c1*x[7]^(0.9)-c2*x[8]^(0.9)-c3*x[9]^(0.9))
    }


eval_g_ineq<-function(x){
h<-numeric(8)
  h[1]<-x[2]-x[1]
  h[2]<-x[3]-x[2]
  h[3]<-x[5]-x[4]
  h[4]<-x[6]-x[5]
  h[5]<-x[8]-x[7]
  h[6]<-x[9]-x[8]
  h[7]<-sum(wp$use)*x[1]+sum(wm$use)*x[2]+sum(wo$use)*x[3]+sum(sp$use)*x[4]+sum(sm$use)*x[5]+sum(so$use)*x[6]+sum(bp$use)*x[7]+sum(bm$use)*x[8]+sum(bo$use)*x[9]-1.1*cost+cost
  h[8]<-(sum(wp$use)*x[1]+sum(wm$use)*x[2]+sum(wo$use)*x[3]+sum(sp$use)*x[4]+sum(sm$use)*x[5]+sum(so$use)*x[6]+sum(bp$use)*x[7]+sum(bm$use)*x[8]+sum(bo$use)*x[9]-1.1*cost+cost)
  return(h)
}

x0<-c(100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100)
......
res<-cobyla(x0,eval_f, lower = lb, upper = NULL,hin = eval_g_ineq,control = list(xtol_rel = 1e-8, maxeval = 10000))
print(res)
```

In the code, h[7] and h[8] is equality constraints. (In the interface, we can also see that 'COBYLA supports equality constraints by transforming them into two inequality constraints.')
However, If i calculate h[7] condition using the solution it does not satisfy that condition. Why it happened?..

**RESULT**

```
> print(res)
$par
[1] 77.54717 77.71680 68.83032 81.49982 73.57022 56.21820 66.57751
[8] 64.44629 55.17281

$value
[1] -9820653

$iter
[1] 4620

$convergence
[1] 4

$message
[1] "NLOPT_XTOL_REACHED: Optimization stopped because xtol_rel or xtol_abs (above) was reached."
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: I think you have to model this as two inequalities.

Comment: Hi @ErwinKalvelagen. Can you elaborate more? I think h[7]<=0, h[8]= -h9[7]<=0 are two inequalities which make equality condition consequently... Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/nloptr/versions/1.2.1/topics/cobyla) says:

> COBYLA supports equality constraints by transforming them into two
>   inequality constraints. As this does not give full satisfaction with
>   the implementation in NLOPT, it has not been made available here.

Of course you can try to reformulate

```
f(x) = 0
```

as

```
f(x) ≥ 0
-f(x) ≥ 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check if your code doesnt have any typos? You do mention you are trying to model the equality as sum of two inequalities but, there seems to be a "-" missing for one of the constraint. (Atleast thats what the code snippet you pasted shows).
Rewriting the code snippet as below:

```
 eval_f<-function(x){                                                        
    -(CCC-a1*x[1]^(0.9)-a2*x[2]^(0.9)-a3*x[3]^(0.9)-b1*x[4]^(0.9)
-b2*x[5]^(0.9)-b3*x[6]^(0.9)-c1*x[7]^(0.9)-c2*x[8]^(0.9)-c3*x[9]^(0.9))
    }


eval_g_ineq<-function(x){
h<-numeric(8)
  h[1]<-x[2]-x[1]
  h[2]<-x[3]-x[2]
  h[3]<-x[5]-x[4]
  h[4]<-x[6]-x[5]
  h[5]<-x[8]-x[7]
  h[6]<-x[9]-x[8]
  h[7]<-sum(wp$use)*x[1]+sum(wm$use)*x[2]+sum(wo$use)*x[3]+sum(sp$use)*x[4]+sum(sm$use)*x[5]+sum(so$use)*x[6]+sum(bp$use)*x[7]+sum(bm$use)*x[8]+sum(bo$use)*x[9]-1.1*cost+cost
  h[8]<- -(sum(wp$use)*x[1]+sum(wm$use)*x[2]+sum(wo$use)*x[3]+sum(sp$use)*x[4]+sum(sm$use)*x[5]+sum(so$use)*x[6]+sum(bp$use)*x[7]+sum(bm$use)*x[8]+sum(bo$use)*x[9]-1.1*cost+cost)
  return(h)
}

x0<-c(100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100)
......
res<-cobyla(x0,eval_f, lower = lb, upper = NULL,hin = eval_g_ineq,control = list(xtol_rel = 1e-8, maxeval = 10000))
print(res)
```